# Starting an ipad app, XCode doesn't do as it should

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So according to this  [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/01_CreatingProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH3-SW3)

"Xcode uses the product name you entered to name your project and the app. Xcode uses the `class prefix` name to name the classes it creates for you. For example, Xcode automatically creates an app delegate class and names it HelloWorldAppDelegate. If you enter a different value for the class prefix, then the app delegate class is named"

However when I create my project, it doesn't create the files with my project name. So instead of `"ProjectNameAppDelegate.h"` I just have `"AppDelegate.h"`. Is there a reason why XCode wouldn't create the proper files I need and how do I fix it?

I also don't have a ViewController.xib file which most online tutorials say I should have. I do have a "MainStoryboard.storyboard but I'm not sure if that counts as the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you mentioned is on an old Xcode. The ***latest Xcode*** wont create appDelegate and ViewController classes by prefixing project name as you said like `ProjectNameAppDelegate.h`. It simply create `AppDelegate.h` only. It is not a bug.

[image]

In the above figure you can see that i have selected ***Use StoryBoards***, So Xcode wont create Xib  files for your viewController instead it will create a storyboard only. Here you dont want xib . Storyboard is replacement for the xib. If you unselect that feature you will get xib back. As a beginner you should go through several  tutorial that uses both xib and storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Anil's answer, Storyboard is a replacement for the old .xib files.